# Performance tuning and Manage Farm-Level Search Settings

Tags: 2007, search, administration, performance, database

Below options are available under "Manage Farm-Level Search Settings" in Central Administration 

Connection time (in seconds): 60

Request acknowledgement time (in seconds): 60

I would like to know that how it affects the SharePoint Performance ?

Let's say, what will be the consequences if we set 90 instead of the default value 60.

Help me with your thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing this value might make your crawl take longer time; it will wait another 30 seconds for requests. And if your crawls take long time and you are crawling from your WFE's it might slightly affect the performance if your crawl takes longer time than the anticipated window in time for crawling.